# PHP PDO MYSQL WHERE ALL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following mysql prepared statement for searching a table. 
In the table there is an is_active column. The users has an option to search true (1), false(0) or All. In the case of all the statement needs to search both true AND false.

As the system is binded through :isActive, what value do I need to apply to :isActive in the event the user wants to search both true and false? Thanks in advance for any help.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT company_id, name, alias, fk_company_type as type, is_active as active
     FROM company 
     WHERE is_active = :isActive 
     AND name LIKE :srchField'
);

$stmt->bindParam(':srchField', $srchField, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
//bind :srchField to $srchField in sql statement
$stmt->bindParam(':isActive', $isActive, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: you would do your check before for all so you'd have an if statement around your prepare and then either prepare a statement with the is_active where clause in it or prepare a statement without the clause.

Comment: can't you just omit the `where` clause in your query or change to allow `< 2` condition in this case?

Comment: YThanks for the inputs Dave and n-dru, I can just have separate if statements but the reason is I wanted to find a way is I also have other conditions to include in the Where. For example the fk_company_type which can be ALL or a certain company type. I was trying to avoid multiple if statements. But it seems the case I may have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a php tag to check the variable is integer or not by using that you can fix this issue.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT company_id, name, alias, fk_company_type as type, is_active as active FROM company WHERE (is_active = :isActive) AND (name LIKE :srchField)');

$stmt->bindParam(':srchField', $srchField, PDO::PARAM_INT); //bind :srchField to $srchField in sql statement

$isActive = is_int($int) ? $int : '0 OR 1';  // $int is an argument which to search option.
$stmt->bindParam(':isActive', $isActive, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: I knew there must be a way to make injection to PDO prepared statements! :)

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it but it seems that PHP is not allowing me to inject the '0 OR 1'. It looks like it only takes 0 and ignores the OR 1. Did you have this issue?